# form validation, getting error while submitting

Tags: forms, validation

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./Style.css";
const SignUp = () => {
  const [register, setRegister] = useState({
    User_name: "",
    User_number: "",
    User_password: "",
    User_email: "",
  });
  const [records, setRecords] = useState([]);

  const handle = (e) => {
    const name = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;
    setRegister({ ...Register, [name]: value });
    console.log(name);
  };

  const Register = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newRecord = { ...Register, id: new Date().getTime().toString() };
    setRecords(...records, newRecord);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <section className="bg">
        <div className="container">
          <form action="" onSubmit={Register}>
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="">Username:</label> <br />
              <input
                type="text"
                name="User_name"
                id="username"
                value={register.User_name}
                required
                onChange={handle}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="">Email:</label>
              <br />
              <input
                type="email"
                name="User_email"
                id="email"
                value={register.User_email}
                required
                onChange={handle}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="">password:</label>
              <br />
              <input
                type="password"
                name=" User_password"
                id="password"
                value={register.User_password}
                required
                onChange={handle}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="">Mobile No:</label>
              <br />
              <input
                type="number"
                name=" User_number"
                id="phone"
                value={register.User_number}
                required
                onChange={handle}
              />
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Register</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  );
};

export default SignUp;
```

while submit the form need to check the all field are filled or not and taking user inputs & managing state. i won't get user inputs into my state. error : A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled. This is likely caused by the value changing from a defined to undefined, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i understand your question... But I do see some issues with your code.

You're trying to update the state using Register (capital "R"). So basically you're trying to spread your function into an object state variable.

```js
const handle = (e) => {
  const name = e.target.name;
  const value = e.target.value;
  setRegister({ ...Register, [name]: value }); // <== change it to ...register
  console.log(name);
};
```

Then in "Register" function, use the spread operator inside an array:

```js
const Register = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const newRecord = { ...register, id: new Date().getTime().toString() };
  setRecords([...records, newRecord]); // <==
};
```

I think your "register" state var could be renamed "user" to avoid mixing things up, and avoid autocomplete misstakes and whatnot.

Hope this helps.